# Can not get Intention.js to work

Tags: javascript, responsive-design

I'm trying to just get a working example of Intention.js up and running so that I can evaluate it for our needs, however I can't even get a simple example to work. It displays both div's despite what "mode" you're in whereas it's only supposed to display one or the other depending on your viewport. I am sure I am missing something not sure what. Any thoughts?

```
<div intent in-standard-append="#desktop" in-tablet-append="#tablet"></div>

<div id="tablet">I'm a tablet</div>
<div id="desktop">I'm a desktop</div>
```

Here's my plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/xbXJbcthykp2UWLFkyfK?p=preview

Here's the Intention.js website:
http://intentionjs.com/

Comment: Your plunker link doesn't work. Site says it can't be found.

Comment: Hey Daniel, that's strange. I can reach it even when not logged into plunkr...

http://plnkr.co/edit/xbXJbcthykp2UWLFkyfK?p=info

Comment: Hmm, I don't know. It's possible that plunker isn't compatibile with my browser (IE 9). It may require one to be logged into github (I am not). It may even be possible that your plunker is somehow saved to your session. Couldn't find plunker documentation, but the link doesn't work for me and I'm sure I'm not alone.

Comment: Plunker link works fine for me but the issue is that the append "command" you're using does not do what you think it does, after glimpsing through the docs it seems it is used for "Placement Manipulation" so it will move the element to a different position based on the viewport size, it won't show/hide elements, see this demo http://plnkr.co/edit/ZySDhHsaCStyvlmSZB0t?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

One of the comments was correct. You're using the function to move an item, rather than change a class. The below example is simplified, but should illustrate the idea of switching classes on two divs depending on the context.

```
<style>
.hidden {display:none;}
.visible {display:block;}
</style>
<div intent in-mobile-class="hidden" in-tablet-class="visible">I'm a tablet</div>
<div intent in-mobile-class="visible" in-tablet-class="hidden">I'm a mobile device</div>
```